# Docker complains it can not update my supported Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker

Docker is giving me a message "A Docker for Windows update is available, but your version of windows isn't supported anymore".

According to [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install):  The current version of Docker for Windows runs on 64bit Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise and Education (1511 November update, Build 10586 or later). In the future we will support more versions of Windows 10.

According my system about page:  I have Windows 10 Pro, 64bit, version 1511, build 10586:1511.

Based on that info, I should have current version.

Is the docker information I have wrong or is there another problem why I cannot get docker to update?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We updated the doc. Sorry, effectively we stopped supporting build 10586 in september, you will need to update to windows build 14393 at least to install Docker For Windows. 
(Alternatively you can use Docker Toolbox on windows)

Guillaume