# Is Docker for Windows available for Windows 10 Enterprise - 10586 Build?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-for-windows

I have tried to download latest docker and it

```
Docker Desktop requires Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise version 14393 to run.
```

My build is :

[image]

It is difficult to find Docker which supports my version and on Google searches i am just finding posts where people are getting same error with 10586 build which suggests that Docker window exists for this build.

Can anyone suggest how to find and install the same?

Comment: Not sure how it is off topic? Even Google is mum and provide no concrete information about this subject. As we have dockerforwindows tag available, i asked this question, if done wrong kindly suggest where should i ask this question other then Docker forums?

Comment: it is a valid question, docker has stopped supporting build 10586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Docker Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46958070/7022485):

> We updated the doc. Sorry, effectively we stopped supporting build
>   10586 in september, you will need to update to windows build 14393 at
>   least to install Docker For Windows. (Alternatively you can use Docker
>   Toolbox on windows)

Comment: Thanks for information. I found a link -> https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/ .... as per info from Docker Developer (Guillaume Tardif) it appears Docker Community Edition 18.06.0-ce-win72 2018-07-26 shall work for me. But he suggest alternative, i shall go by that. Searching. Thanks